# How to disable the PIE protect by patching the ELF?

Tags: elf, aslr

From the perspective of processing, disabling the ASLR(not PIE)is simple with the instruction "ASLR OFF" in gdb, but for this way ,we have only changed the kernel model but not the elf itself.Actually the program still defended with PIE protection.
So if there exist the method to patch the ELF binary to disable PIE protect entirely?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?  Do you want to actually patch out the pc-relative memory access instructions in the binary and replace them all with absolute addresses?  I don't think that'll be possible in general, especially on architectures like x86 with variable-length instructions.

Comment: But I don't understand how position-independent code in itself is a "protection" or "defends" the program in any way.  AFAIK its only security benefit is to make it *possible* to use ASLR.  If there's an attack method that would work on a non-PIE binary, it's very likely to also work on a PIE binary with ASLR disabled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> So if there exist the method to patch the ELF binary to disable PIE protect entirely?

PIE binaries are usually linked at address 0, and require relocation before they can run.

You *may* be able to disable ASLR for a particular binary by

1. `prelink`ing to a different address and
2. changing the `ElfXXEhdr.e_type` from `ET_DYN` to `ET_EXEC`